# problem in taking input for the char type in c

Tags: c, pointers

i am having a trouble in taking input for the character type in c.the behavior of my source code is unusual.

my **code** is:

```
int n,i;
char *ps;

printf("Total no:");

scanf("%d",&n);

ps=(char *)calloc(n,sizeof(char));

for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    printf("Enter character %d:",i+1);
    scanf("%c",ps+i);
}
```

then as per my requirement it should take input for all no. of n's but it's not working fine it will not take any input when the loop runs for the first time then it take input 
when  loop runs 2 time and then in 4 time and so on.

so please tell me what's the error with my code?

-Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scanf calls do not include the newline, so when you enter "5 [enter]" as input, the first scanf reads in the "5" and the second reads the newline.  Try changing your scanf calls to look like `scanf("%d\n", &n)` or `scanf("%d%*c", &n)` to explicitly handle the newline.

Answer (score 4):

Each call to `scanf` inside the loop reads the next character. If you enter, for example:

`Total no:`<kbd>4</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then the first `scanf` will read `4` as an `int`, but the <kbd>Enter</kbd> will be seen by the next `scanf` (inside the loop) as a newline, `\n`.

Change the first call to `scanf("%d\n", &n)` and the one inside the loop to `scanf("%c\n",ps+i)`.